# Является ли решение хорошим с точки зрения "антикостыльности"?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Столкнулся с задачей: есть список комплексных чисес `vertexes = [v0, v1, ..., vn]`, необходимо получить список `distances = [d0, d1, ..., ]`, причём `distances[i] = abs(vertexes[i + 1] - vertexes[i])`

Например, `vertexes = [1 + 0j, 3 + 0j, 3 + 4j, 6 + 8j] => distances = [2, 4, 5]`

Моё решение:

```
import functools

def calculate_distances(vertexes):
    distances = []

    functools.reduce(lambda a, b: distances.append(abs(b - a)) or b, vertexes)

    return distances


vertexes = [1 + 0j, 3 + 0j, 3 + 4j, 6 + 8j]

distances = calculate_distances(vertexes)

print(distances)

# Out: [2.0, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Стоит ли писать такой код? Может есть решение изящнее или правильнее или (изящнее и правильнее)? После такого у меня остаётся ужасное послевкусие костыльности. Так ли это на самом деле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну я бы вообще вот так написал:

```
distances = [abs(b - a) for b,a in zip(vertexes[1:],vertexes)]
```

Comment: очень красивое решение!

Comment: @ТимурМашарипов Списковые сокращения почти любые задачи позволяют в питоне решать. А к `reduce` я неравнодушен, но сколько ни пытался его куда-то применить, обычно без него попроще решение находится.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы так делал:

```
import itertools

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = itertools.tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

def calculate_distances(vertexes):
    return [abs(b - a) for a, b in pairwise(vertexes)]


vertexes = [1 + 0j, 3 + 0j, 3 + 4j, 6 + 8j]

distances = calculate_distances(vertexes)

print(distances)
```